# How to update input type="text" value with var javascript onchange even?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to update input `type="text"` value with var javascript `onchange` even ?

http://jsfiddle.net/A4wxX/84/

First, Fill `10000.225` into input `type="text"` and then it's will be alert `10,000.23` (with my function auto `ReplaceNumberWithCommas` AND `roundFloat`)

This is my question,

i want to update input `type="text"` with `var zzz` (replace old value  `EG: replace 10000.225 with 10,000.23` ) , How can i do that ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function SetCard() {
    var number_var = document.getElementById("number").value;        

    function ReplaceNumberWithCommas(yourNumber) {
        //Seperates the components of the number
        var components = yourNumber.toString().split(".");
        //Comma-fies the first part
        components [0] = components [0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        //Combines the two sections
        return components.join(".");
    }

    function roundFloat(num,dec){
        var d = 1;
        for (var i=0; i<dec; i++){
            d += "0";
        }
        return Math.round(num * d) / d;
    }

    var xxx = number_var;

    var yyy = Math.round(xxx * 100) / 100;
    var zzz = (ReplaceNumberWithCommas(yyy));

    alert(zzz);
}   
</script>

<input type="text" id="number" onchange="SetCard()">
```

Comment: document.getElementById("number").value = zzz;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using pure javascript:

```
document.getElementById("number").value = zzz;
```

Answer (score 2):

use jQuery to set the value. This sets the value of the variable `zzz` to be the value where the ID is `number`

```
$('#number').val(zzz);
```

You're already using jQuery, but if you want a pure JS version you can do

```
document.getElementById('number').value = zzz;
```

Comment: No indication that he's using jQuery.

Comment: @id.ot his code sample includes jQuery and the question is tagged jQuery

Answer (score 1):

just using `document.getElementById("number").value = zzz;`